# Adding documents result to an Array<Object> variable with cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im having an issue trying to put the result of all documents in an ArrayList variable, I can get the results but I can only use them inside the onComplete method. I can even set my txtviews with the data I get but I cant store it in the Arraylist. I use this var as a parameter of my adapter to view all these items in a ListView. What am i doing wrong?

```
public List<Producto> menu;
menu= new ArrayList<Product>();
//Reference to the collection I want to get all documents
colRef
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        int i = 0;
                        for(DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                            Product product = document.toObject(Product.class);

                            menu.add(producto);
                            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, ""+menu.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            i++;
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, ""+productosMenu.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Toast on the loop, shows the data saved into the ArrayList but outside the listener I validate the size of the ArrayList again and i get a 0 size, and off course my screen is empty cause the adapter cant read any item on the Array...
Im new into android and firebase but trying to learn, Im making a restaurant app. I appreciate if someone can guide me, I cant find any other clue of what im doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized I forgot to change the  var name at the last Toast, but is not like im calling a different variable, I meant menu.size().

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method is asynchronous.  It returns immediately while the query is being performed.  This means that that your `menu` array will be empty at the time the Toast is performed on the last line.

If you want to perform some work only after a query is complete, do it in the callback from the Task returned by `get()`, where you are currently iterating the documents in the result.

Comment: Thanks man! Now the data is stored and the listView uploads all the documents info, I have really looked for clues on the documentation but havent realize the fact of `get()` method is asynchronous. Again thank you, I remember you from the starter videos of Firebase :). Greetings from Colombia!

Comment: Any Firebase API method that returns a `Task` object is asynchronous.  There are absolutely no blocking API calls in Firebase SDKs anywhere, by design.